# Building a Chrome Extension to Check the Active URL against a List of URLs

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome extension for my company to check the currently active URL's domain against a list of domains on an external webpage (possibly with authentication) that we will update.

I know very little about building Chrome extensions. I have managed to build a button with a custom graphic that says "BOO!" when it is clicked; that's the extent of my knowledge.

To my understanding, I will require these files:

```
•  manifest.json
•  icon.png
•  negative.png*
•  popup.html
•  popup.js
```

*`negative.png` will be what the button icon "changes" to if the active URL's domain is detected within the list of domains, which will sit on an external webpage. As a flag that the active URL's domain is present in the list, if you will.

I don't really know **anything** about JavaScript or JSON, can someone help me get started? What's some "rough" code that I might use to accomplish something like this?

I don't even know which file will be the file that detects the active URL's domain against our list, or which file will be the one that changes the button graphic.

I have tried searching Google for guides but all of the Chrome extension building guides are overly simplistic. Also, because most people searching for "Chrome extension"-related stuff are end-users, Google merely produces lists of query results that are actual pre-built extensions. I'm looking for info on how to build one, not the nearest existing equivalent.

This will be as much a learning exercise for me as anything else.

Comment: _I don't really know anything about JavaScript or JSON, can someone help me get started?_ Sorry, but Stack Overflow is the wrong place to ask in this case. Please look at these guides about Stack Overflow: site [tour], [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What is on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Especially the fact that asking for tutorials is off-topic.

Comment: That said, I don't want to leave you _completely_ without help. Start with the [Overview page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) of extension documentation. Come back here when you have well-defined problems that comply with the SO policies I cited above, and we'll help.

Comment: Thanks Xan! I'll be sure to go and read all the documentation thoroughly and try to post something more on-topic. I've actually almost managed to make an extension that cites the active chrome URL when clicked, but unluckily it just quotes the installation URL of the extension (rather than the active URL from chromes address bar)